# Django: Custom model manager problem

Tags: django

I am trying a simple custom manager, but I can't concatenate custom queries:

```
class MyManager(models.Manager):    
def some_filter(self):        
    qs = self.get_query_set()
    return qs.filter(score__gt = 10).order_by("-score")
class Game(models.Model):    
     score = models.IntegerField(blank=True, default=0)
     objects = MyManager()


games = Game.objects.filter(any_filter).some_filter()[:5]
```

But I get QuerySet' object has no attribute 'some_filter'

**Edit**: It appears that the question is how to concatenate **custom** filter functions together: seomthing like `games = Game.objects.some_filter1().some_filter2()[:5]` just won't work for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a way to do it. A new QuerySet class need to be defined too

```
class GameQS(QuerySet):
    def some_filter1(self):
        return self.filter(score__gt = 10).order_by("-score")
    def some_filter2(self):
        return self.filter(score__gt = 50).order_by("-score")



class GameManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        return GameQS(self.model, using=self._db)

    def some_filer1(self):
        return self.get_query_set().some_filter1()

    def some_filter2(self):
        return self.get_query_set().some_filter2()
```

Answer (score 4):

You can apply some_filter() to MyManager object before QuerySet method filter()

```
games = Game.objects.some_filter().filter(any_filter)[:5]
```

Otherwise you should add some_filter method to QuerySet

Comment: Yes but that doesn't solve the problem if I have 2 filters defined in MyManager: Game.objects.some_filter().some_filter2() won't work

Answer (score 0):

If you are new in using model managers, first see [GabiMe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3847933/3857234)

From django 1.7 onward, use [queryset as manager class method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.as_manager) to keep code DRY

```
MyQueryset.as_manager()
```

If you are using older verssions refer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2163151/custom-queryset-and-manager-without-breaking-dry) for more ways to optimize the code.