# how can i limit my django foreign key selection by a property stored in the django session

Tags: python, django, session-variables

i have a small application i am implementing with django and i'm having a slight challenge. I'm trying to limit the queryset for my relationships within my application by a particular property. Now the catch is, the exact value of the property isn't known until the user logs into the application. an example is limiting a set of comments by a user's particular company, and the company is only determined when the user logs in. I don't know how to find my current session outside a django view. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Here is a sample of a model from my application

```
class Tax(commons.models.EntityBase):
    name = models.CharField(blank=False, max_length=150)
    percentage_value = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=2)
    notes = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    auto_apply = models.NullBooleanField()
    aggregated_tax = models.NullBooleanField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

Every entity inherits from the abstract class `EntityBase`, which holds the property `company`. I want to filter every query from the query manager such that they only return entities who's company are equal to the company in the session.

Comment: Where are you using the querysets that need the company filter? Wouldn't that be in the view, or a form created in a view?

Comment: Post your existing view and model.

Comment: I want to use the company filter in my model's queryset. This means i don't have access to the request context which, as far as i know, is only available within a view.

Answer (score 1):

It is perfectly ok to pass your session property, user or company or whatnot, to other functions in different parts of your system.

For example:

```
def view(request):
    user = request.user
    filtered_stuff = my_filter_function(..., user = user)
```

The `my_filter_function` may filter on the argument or may pass on the argument to other functions.

Answer (score 0):

The best way that I've found to do this is using a custom `QuerySet` and Manager for your model.  The accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2163151/custom-queryset-and-manager-without-breaking-dry/2163921#2163921), should get you started with this part.  In your `QuerySet`, you can set up a method (I prefer to call it `for_user`), which filters your objects for you:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    ts = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)
    due_date = models.DateField(auto_now=False)
    objects = CustomQuerySetManager()
    class QuerySet(QuerySet):
        def for_user(self, user):
            return self.filter(user=user)
```

From there, your view is fairly simple:

```
def view(request):
    user = request.user
    mylist = Foo.objects.for_user(user).filter(due_date__lte=datetime.date.today())
```

Comment: In this case I think it would make a lot more sense to use a method on the manager, instead of creating a custom QuerySet.

Comment: Actually, that's where the `CustomQuerySetManager` comes in handy from the other question.  The code from the `QuerySet` works in the Manager as well.  No breaking DRY.

Answer (score 0):

To add to Jack's answer, 
your CustomQuerySetManager would be something like:

```
class CustomQuerySetManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        return self.model.QuerySet(self.model)
    def __getattr__(self, attr, *args):
        return getattr(self.get_query_set(), attr, *args)
```

I prefer this method over writing manager methods because it allows you to have chainable functions, therefore you could do:

```
Foo.objects.for_user(user).filter(...)
```