# How Django QuerySet initialization works?

Tags: django, django-queryset

I'm referring to the code snippet in the first answer taken from
this post: [Custom QuerySet and Manager without breaking DRY?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2163151/custom-queryset-and-manager-without-breaking-dry)

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.query import QuerySet

    class CustomQuerySetManager(models.Manager):
        """A re-usable Manager to access a custom QuerySet"""
        def __getattr__(self, attr, *args):
            try:
                return getattr(self.__class__, attr, *args)
            except AttributeError:
                return getattr(self.get_query_set(), attr, *args)

        def get_query_set(self):
            return self.model.QuerySet(self.model)
```

Here is the model:

```
from custom_queryset.models import CustomQuerySetManager
from django.db.models.query import QuerySet

class Inquiry(models.Model):
    objects = CustomQuerySetManager()

    class QuerySet(QuerySet):
        def active_for_account(self, account):
            self.filter(account = account, deleted=False, *args, **kwargs)
```

`self.model.QuerySet(self.model)` always receives a same model, but the result QuerySet depends on the input QuerySet. For example:

`Inquiry.objects.all()[:5].active_for_account(xyz)`, then `active_for_account` will receive a query set of 5 items, while in `Inquiry.objects.all()[:7].active_for_account(xyz)`,  `active_for_account` will receive a query set of 7 items. Here are stack traces:

```
Inquiry.objects.all()[:5].active_for_account(xyz) 
    return getattr(self.get_query_set(), attr, *args),
       return self.model.QuerySet(self.model)   (1)

Inquiry.objects.all()[:7].active_for_account(xyz) 
    return getattr(self.get_query_set(), attr, *args),
       return self.model.QuerySet(self.model)   (2)
```

Why are results at (1) and (2) different?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what you're asking here.

`Inquiry.objects.all()[:5]` doesn't give you give objects, it gives you a single QuerySet object which contains five elements.