# Using Django custom manager function on an already filtered queryset

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-managers

Consider the following case:

```
class MyModelManager(models.Manager):
    def my_filter(self):
     return [some code here].filter(field_A__gt=3)

class MyModel(models.Model):
    # some fields
    objects = MyModelManager()


# The way I'd like to use it:
qs = MyModel.objects.filter(field_B__lt=1)
# some code
qs = qs.my_filter()
```

Notice that I'd like to use the custom `my_filter()` function on the already filtered queryset. What code should I place in the `[some code here]` above? Is the structure as a whole correct?

Comment: See also question #2163151: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2163151/custom-queryset-and-manager-without-breaking-dry

Answer (score 2):

I guess there is no way to do it exactly this way.
    MyModel.objects.filter(field_B__lt=1)
will return QuerySet object, not MyModelManager.
You may either pass it to my_filter method as Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams mentioned or first apply my_filter to your manager, that will return QuerySet object, that you can filter further

Comment: How come then that MyModel.objects.filter(...).filter(...) works?

Comment: so both Manager and QuerySet have filter()?

Comment: From django source Manager class methods:
def get_query_set(self):
        """Returns a new QuerySet object.  Subclasses can override this method
        to easily customize the behavior of the Manager.
        """
        return QuerySet(self.model, using=self._db)
def filter(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.get_query_set().filter(*args, **kwargs)

So Manager creates new QuerySet and apply filter to it

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is wrong because you can only use Model.Manager while you retreive data from database, so using two managers or trying to use a manager ona a queryset causes error.

```
data = SomeModel.objects.my_manager.all()
```

or

```
data = SomeModel.objects.all()
data = data.my_manager.filter(...)
```

is wrong since you can not use two managers...

One possible waw is defining a function that gets a queryset as a parameter and returns a filtered queryset...

```
def extra_filter(queryset):
    queryset = queryset.filter(...)
```

but i am not sure if this helps.

Best approach is defining another model Manager and use it instread of **objects** if required...

```
class SomeManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        return super(SomeManager, self).get_query_set().filter(<filteer criteria>)

class MyModel(models.Model):
    # some fields
    objects = models.Manager()
    mymanager = SomeManager()

data = MyModel.mymanager.all()
```

And use just one...

UPDATE: In django, querysets are lazy. That means, you can apply as many filters as you wish and data will not be retreived from the database unliess you try to get a specific record from the filtered or you try to slice it...[Documentation is here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy)

So, there is no diffrence between

```
qs = MyModel.objects.filter(field_B__lt=1)
qs = qs.filter(field_A__gt=3)
```

and

```
qs = MyModel.objects.filter(field_A__gt=3)
qs = qs.filter(field_B__lt=1)
```

So defining a manager to apply a **specific** filtering is the main reason for using managers...

You define your manager :

```
class SomeManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        return super(SomeManager, self).get_query_set().filter(field_A__gt=3)
```

then you call it with other filtering criteria:

```
Somemodel.mymodelmanager.filter(field_B__lt=1, ....)
```

And django will add all filters and evluate the query when you want  it to do.

So if it is a filter that you use oftenly, manager i the best choice...

As for an example, i have *valid*_ field in my most database models and a **val** manager that filters invalid entries. So When i wish to filter all valid data (90% of the time) i use

```
Somemodel.val.filter(...)
```

And in the situation that i need all the data i just use basic django manager:

```
Somemodel.objects.filter(...)
```

Comment: I'm trying to use a custom filtering function on an already regularly filtered queryset,  don't see how defining another manager would achieve that

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyModelManager(models.Manager):
    def my_filter(self, qs=None):
        if qs is None:
            qs = [however you got it before]
        return qs.filter(field_A__gt=3)
```

Then just pass your queryset to it.

Comment: Isn't that a workaround? the code would be something like: qs = MyModel.objects.my_filter(qs)  which is less djangoic than what I'd expect

Comment: How else would you expect to be able to get the queryset in?

Comment: `filter()` is a `QuerySet` method.

Comment: So do I need to override QuerySet and add my_function, instead of adding it to the manager?

Comment: If you want it to be a `QuerySet` method, sure.