# In Django, how does one change a field name in field lookup?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

Field lookups in django use field names in the form in which they are declared in the code. Is there any way to provide a custom name for a field, to be used in lookups only?

I would like to use it to make a field read-only, but still be able to use it normally in queries.

For example, if the model looks like this:

```py
class Flight(models.Model):
    _cancelled = models.BooleanField()

    @property
    def cancelled(self):
        return self._cancelled
```

Then filtering has to be done like this:

```py
Flight.objects.all().filter(_cancelled=True)
```

And since we want the outside world to use `cancelled` as the property, it would be nicer if we could write:

```py
Flight.objects.all().filter(cancelled=True)
```

I have tried using Field.db_column property, but it only appears to change the column name in the database.

For the sample case above, a proper Manager would be enough to handle this, but things become more complicated if there is another model with ForeignKey to `Flight`, and we want to make queries on that other model, still filtering for `cancelled=True`.

Answer (score 1):

[CustomQuerySetManager](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2163921/2639576) allows you to easily add methods do *QuerySets* instead of manager itself, so you could write your `cancelled()` method and have it available everywhere, even in related models.

`Flight.objects.cancelled()`

It's chainable:
`Flight.objects.filter(...).cancelled().update(...)`

It can be used in related models:
`Airport.flights.cancelled()`

Quick example:

```
class Flight(models.Model):
    objects = CustomQuerySetManager()

    # Nested class definition, similar to the Meta class
    class QuerySet(QuerySet):  
        def cancelled(self):
            return self.filter(_cancelled=True)
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. What if you're looking up through a M2M or FK for example?