# how to exclude non-active users from queryset in django

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-rest-framework

I want to exclude non-active users from my project.

```
example 1:
  url:users/1/friends/ will show all friends of that user.
```

I want to show only active users in friend list.

```
example 2:
  url:users/1/friends/ will show all friends of that user.
```

if user with id 1 is not active i don't want to show any activity of him..like his friends..his profile...etc

```
example 3:
  url:users/1/challenge/  will show all friends of that user in post form.
```

i don't want to show non-active users in form.

is there any generic way to perform this. Because its a big project  and I can't make filter everywhere.

Tables are like:

```
class User(models.Model):
  ......
  ......
  friends = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

Answer (score 7):

You should use a custom Model Manager:

```
class ActiveUsersManager(models.Manager):
    use_for_related_fields = True

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(ActiveUserManager, self).get_queryset().filter(is_active=True)


class User(models.Model):
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=true)

    # first manager is the default and accessible through objects.
    active = ActiveUsersManager()
    all_users = models.Manager()

active_users = User.objects.all()    
all_users = User.all_users.all()
```

Comment: thank ...but i am working on django rest framework and when a form is created by rest framework to post a request it automatically shows all entries of a ForeignkeyField. Means manager doesn't work at that time.

Comment: If I get it right, `use_for_related_fields = true` should be solving this.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to exclude non-active users from a queryset you can use the following filter:

```
YourModel.objects.exclude(friend__is_active=False)

# or 
YourModel.objects.filter(friend__is_active=True)
```

Where `friend` is a `ForeignKeyField` to a `User` model object in `YourModel`.

If you want a more general solution, you can use a `ModelManager`:

```
class ActiveUsersOnlyManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(ActiveUsersOnlyManager, self).get_queryset().filter(is_active=True)


class User(models.Model):
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=true)
    friends = models.ForeignKey(User)
    # first manager is the default and accessible through objects.
    objects = ActiveUsersManager()
```

Comment: i know that ....i want a generic solution so that i ll not need to filter the queryset everywhere , as you said above.

Comment: thank ...but i am working on django rest framework and when a form is created by rest framework to post a request it automatically shows all entries of a ForeignkeyField. Means manager doesn't work at that time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Creating a manager with QuerySet methods](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/managers/#creating-a-manager-with-queryset-methods)

> can be used to create an instance of Manager with a copy of a custom QuerySet’s methods

```
class UserQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def active(self):
        return self.filter(is_active=True)

class User(models.Model):
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=true)

    objects = UserQuerySet.as_manager()
```

And use it simply like this

`User.objects.active()`

For custom users (`AbstractUser`) you need this solution
It is based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2163921/5751147)

```
from django.db.models import QuerySet
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser, UserManager


class UserQuerySetManager(UserManager):
    def __getattr__(self, attr, *args):
        try:
            return getattr(self.__class__, attr, *args)
        except AttributeError:
            # don't delegate internal methods to the queryset
            if attr.startswith('__') and attr.endswith('__'):
                raise
            return getattr(self.get_query_set(), attr, *args)

    def get_query_set(self):
        return self.model.QuerySet(self.model, using=self._db)


class User(AbstractUser):
    objects = UserQuerySetManager()


    class Meta:
        permissions = (
            ('view_all_managers', 'View All Managers'),
        )

    class QuerySet(QuerySet):
        def active(self):
            return self.filter(is_active=True)
```