# Django Custom model manager and Modeladmin

Tags: python, django

I have an app called `article`. I want to hide articles with `hidden = True`. All hidden articles should not be findable except for admins.

I'm using a custom manager and I'm using a custom Modeladmin.

my custom modeladmin:

```
class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super().get_queryset(request)
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return qs
        return qs.filter(hidden=False)
```

my custom manager:

```
class ArticleManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
         qs = super().get_queryset()
         return qs.filter(hidden=False)
```

I want to get all articles with `hidden = False` when I use `Article.objects.all()` and when I'm in the admin panel I also want to get articles with `hidden = True`.

Admin panel -> All articles
Article.objects.all() -> All articles with `hidden = False`

**What's working:**
When I use Article.objects.all() I get all articles with `hidden = False`

**What's not working:**
When I'm on the admin panel I don't see any articles with `hidden = True`.

Only in the admin panel articles with `hidden = True` should be visible. In Sitemaps, Querysets ... they shouldnt be returned.

Comment: Ok. What's the question?

Comment: Can you add more to the problem you are facing. Describe what you are expecting and what is not working.

Comment: @BidhanMajhi I've updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the better practice is to define QuerySet as a custom inner class and then pass it to a manager. Then you have various options - you can just define two querysets and use a specific one for your administrators or you can do User rights check directly in your manager class as it's done, for example, in answer to this question. Then you can just use `objects.all()` and it will return different results for different users.

[Custom QuerySet and Manager without breaking DRY?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2163151/custom-queryset-and-manager-without-breaking-dry)

Hope it will help ^^

Comment: Ok thanks. I defined `all` to give all articles with `hidden = False` and now I want to return all articles with `admin_all`. How do I call this in admin?