# Django - CustomQuerySet only works in objects

Tags: python, django

I'm using a CustomQuerySet using [Custom QuerySet and Manager without breaking DRY?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2163151/custom-queryset-and-manager-without-breaking-dry). I can only access custom functions using `objects`. Here's my Code:

```
class CustomQuerySetManager(models.Manager):
    """A re-usable Manager to access a custom QuerySet"""
    def __getattr__(self, attr, *args):
        print(attr)
        try:
            return getattr(self.__class__, attr, *args)
        except AttributeError:
            # don't delegate internal methods to the queryset
            if attr.startswith('__') and attr.endswith('__'):
                raise
            return getattr(self.get_query_set(), attr, *args)

    def get_query_set(self):
        return self.model.QuerySet(self.model, using=self._db)


class SampleModel(models.Model):
    objects = CustomQuerySetManager()

    class QuerySet(models.QuerySet):
        def test(self):
            print("test function was callsed")
```

With this these happens:

```
SampleModel.objects.test() # This works
SampleModel.objects.all().test() # This doesnt works...
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: Because the `.all()` returns a `QuerySet` (not the one you defined, but the "vanilla" `QuerySet`). Your own `QuerySet` after all implements these methods, and a `QuerySet` always makes a *copy*, so the output `.all()` is *not* the same `QuerySet` object, it is a new `QuerySet`, but with the same data.

Comment: Is there any way to not get the "vanilla" `Queryset`? This answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/2163921/9878135) says it should be possible. Do you have any idea?

Comment: @Myzei394: yes, you will need to patch all methods to wrap the result in your `CustomQuerySet`. See the source code of the `QuerySet`: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/query.py#L185

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Idk what you mean with patch. I've never done this. Can you give me an example please?